# Is using a non-GFCI circuit more risky now than before GFCI entered the electrical code?

Tags: electrical, gfci, safety

When using a non-GFCI grounded receptacle with a modern device (e.g. manufactured date 21st century) are the risks the same as they were in pre-GFCI era?

I can imagine some situations in which risk is higher, for example if manufacturers have learned to skimp on their devices because of the added safety of GFCI-code (not that this would make sense from a liability standpoint).

If I am content with the level of safety during my childhood, what benefits does a GFCI circuit offer? (Assume neither my local code nor insurance require the circuit to be updated to GFCI.  Neglect risks/burdens to others, such as emergency responders, or such as another user of the circuit.)

**EDIT Sept 19 2017:** This question is about to be closed for being too broad. Despite that possibility, and despite the cruft below, it has been answered as far as I am concerned. Still, I thought I'd add a follow up to help clarify my question so as to meet forum guidelines, then bug out. While one person noted more devices are including built in GFIs nowadays, no one noted manufactures were skimping based on the uptick in GFCIs.  Devices may be more 'cheaply made', whatever that means, but they are still listed and labeled.  As far as I know, no ordinary devices have manufacturer requirements stipulating plugging into a GFCI receptacle or a GFCI adapter.  Also, as far as I know, there are no regulations that require plugging a device into a GFCI when using the device around water.  I assume that to mean that the powers-that-be are content with the level of safety when using listed and labeled devices in non-GFCI receptacles.

Comment: not many people in the US who die from electrocution die from 110v. It's not impossible, but these types of fast (15-40ms) cut-offs are a lot more important with 220v systems. you're not "less safe" than before.

Comment: What are you fishing for here, an excuse not to install a GFCI?  Obviously.  Well, do what you want.

Comment: Is flying in a Ford Trimotor more risky now that the Boeing Dreamliner is out and is uber-safe?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because products are much more cheaply made today than before.

Also they are no longer grounded.

You should see some of the dreck on the market. Follow any of the Youtube videos where EE's do teardowns of consumer products.  It's appalling.

The reason not to rely on "past safety standards you were happy with" is the winner's bias: you're only happy with them because you got lucky.  The dice don't care. **Dice have no memory**.  Every day they roll again, and every day it's a new risk.  If Russian Roulette works twice, stop doing it!   Now if a $20 gadget increases your odds by like 95%, statistically that's a good play.

People's resistance to GFCI is often based on wild misestimates of cost.  For instance believing you need one per receptacle, at $20 each that adds up fast.   Incorrect, if you apply a little education, you can use them as intended and use one per circuit.

Comment: Yeah, the trend in consumer gear is to double insulation vs. earthing -- but that makes the design of things like transformers critically important

Comment: other things constant, my risk now is lower since I am much older, but not too old, yet (that's around the corner). male youth is a risky business.

Comment: How do you ground plastic or get a shock from plastic? OP never mentioned cost but quality and risk.

Comment: @EdBeal -- double insulation makes "wire to case" faults go away, but it combines with the rise of the switching supply to make things like transformer construction critically important.  [Case in point, from the UK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Hdn0MuCK_0)

Comment: @David you spend too much time around actuaries.  That is complete bull.  I get it, you dislike GFCIs for some reason, and are straining to justify other reasons.  Knock it off, don't lie, stick to the courage of your convictions.  If that's "because I'm an ornery old coot and you can't make me think modern" then so be it.

Comment: Harper how many times have you been asked to remove a GFCI for false tripping problems? I know I have and have never done it but told the home owner how to do it. Both AFCI's & GFCI' have there place but my belief is current code has gone two far. Eliminate back stabs and old aluminum wire (to devices) and +75% of the problems I have repaired in my lifetime would be gone. How many freezers have thawed because of GFCI'S my state exempts them from GFCI requirements. Keep AFCI'S in bedroom outlet circuits and GFCI's where there is water but other than that I see them causing more problems.

Comment: @EdBeal I can't deny current code has taken GFCI and AFCI too far.  Especially in fridges/freezers.  I do say GFCIs are generally useful, and "the other David" had a picture postcard example of why, with his Sawzall that was trying to kill him.  Often those aren't really nuisance trips, they are actual ground faults people stubbornly don't want to fix.  If Harbor Freight gave away free meggers with any purchase, there'd be a lot more awareness that ground faults are a real thing.

Comment: I agree ground faults are a real thing, however I have several meggers and none of my equipment that trips them has ever shown a problem and several trip GFCI's 100% of the time and these are top of the line tools but I have a few HF also.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your question from another angle.

> If you stopped using your seat belt, would you have less accidents
>   because you would be more likely to be hurt or dead?

That question is similar to the question you are asking. The upgrade to all codes are necessary because people were being injured or dying. Now with the newer codes there is less of a chance of a possible burn or electric shock. Preventing accidents is a progressive and proactive response to new data and the increase and use of new electrical products.

You might think these codes are written as a humanitarian effort, but it's not. These codes are written by the NFPA and they are the underwriters for all insurable interests in the US. So the insurance company gets tired of writing people checks for accidents that can be prevented, and acts upon it by trying to prevent them through the update of codes. In short if we as electricians don't follow these required codes then the insurance companies won't insure the installation or require higher premiums to cover their costs.

In conclusion updates for more safe installations are really not up to public opinion. They are required from people who have an interest in preventing accidents and in this state it becomes law. And as someone who is licensed by the state we sign an agreement to obey the law or face penalties, loss of license, and/or criminal prosecution whether we like it or not.

Comment: I'm not sure how your write up addresses my question, but I appreciate your perspective.  correct me if i am wrong ... it sounds like you are saying that code upgrades such as GFCIs are not driven by the humanitarian aim of society to avoid accidental deaths, but they are driven by the financial aim of the insurance companies to increase profits?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

- My wife replaces her hair dryer every few years and they still come with their own GFI. A lot more devices designed to work around water have them as well, likely due to legal liability
- Most devices have never been designed to work around water. My wife uses a crock pot on our kitchen counter next to the sink. It could fall in, but I have a GFI there for that reason. The crock pot has no reason to expect it will be used next to a sink.

Remember, the GFI is there to prevent electrocution. If you're OK being electrocuted, carry on.

Comment: I'm okay with the level of risk of electrocution that I had when a kid.  From a quick google search there are a couple hundred electrocutions per year now-a-days, versus, say 35,000 suicides. That is 100:1 ratio. If GFCIs eliminated 90% of electrocutions, then the ratio is still 10:1.  FWIW, last year for the first time, fewer people died in traffic accidents than committed suicide.

Comment: So, what I take away from that comment: You can go to therapy and get GFCIs to be uber-safe (but not in an Uber).

Comment: For a receptacle that meets code and insurance requirements, would  replacing it with a GFCI indicate the money would have been better spent on the implied needed therapy?

Comment: While YMMV on price, you can get a basic 15A GFI for about $12-14. Your average therapist is going to charge a lot more than that.

Comment: My understanding is that the rule of thumb is that the smaller the scope of an insurance policy, the less value you get (if any) for the money.

Answer (score 0):

I would say today's devices are safer because of plastics used for the cases where in years past the cases were metal.  Would you be safer having GFCI'S? Sure GFCIs limit the amount of current to prevent electrocution but you can still receive a shock that hurts. I recommend GFCI's. For all out door outlets and bathrooms in older homes because this is where the highest risk is. Yes within 6' of a sink is a good idea. But as far as device safety I would say things are safer because of lawsuits in the past and the materials used in modern manufacturing.

Comment: Our house meets modern GFCI standards in the kitchen, and baths, but not in the garage. No outdoor outlets.

Comment: My garage was built before GFCI'S were required so it is up to code for when it was built. I will not be changing to GFCI'S because of the nuisance tripping of the equipment I run. Code dosent require the update so why do it in my shop. I think my answer and TFK did answer your question if you have more to ask edit your question.

Comment: I had a modern house previously, which meant a GFI on the garage circuit. When it was humid (not necessarily raining) the freezer would trip the GFI. I wound up putting a standard outlet in (I never consider the garage a "wet" zone). One of the few places I would say a GFI is overkill

Answer (score 0):

> If I am content with the level of safety during my childhood, what benefits does a GFCI circuit offer?

It offers exactly what a GFCI offers: protection from a ground fault. The difference in the level of safety previously and currently is that it is an automatic disconnect when things go wrong. Sure you might not have gotten zapped, and in most cases you can play things safely yourself to prevent possible cases (like not using or placing electrical devices by water sources), but what about when things don't go as planned or an accident happens?

A GFCI is essentially insurance if there are greater chances for a ground fault.

Comment: Are you saying no useful benefit if I am content with the level of safety during my childhood?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. There is a benefit, you can just choose not to upgrade to it. The code continues to be revised and modern code is definitely safer than in past times, but there is risk in everything that is done. Being up to date means a higher level of safety, but it doesn't mean you will be electrocuted or burn your house down if you don't.

Comment: What is the benefit I am content with the level of safety during my childhood?

Comment: The benefit is the GFI outlet being able to automatically shut off the power if you got zapped. Whereas previously you would just continue to get zapped. That's the benefit, but you can choose not to need it.

Comment: I am content with the zapping to which I was vulnerable during my childhood. I take your answer to be 'No benefit'.

Comment: Similar to your case of the garage, I have a couple outlets in my unfinished basement that aren't GFCI. Although it's not up to code, I don't see any benefit myself to changing them currently because I hardly use them. If this is the answer you want, then it's true there isn't directly a benefit for me. However this isn't a sweeping answer, it depends on the locations and usage of the outlets.